# Is there anyway to use BULK INSERT from .txt file and choose specific column to import into SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a `.txt` file that consists of around 80 columns and 1,900,000 rows. I want to import specific columns into SQL Server using `BULK INSERT` and make a new table but I kept getting an error that says the column format is wrong. I also need to keep NULLS since some columns have NULL. I created a new table that consists of all the columns that I chose out of the 80 columns. I tried to import this data through the Import and Export wizard and it took me around 10 hours which is strange, that is why I want to try importing it through query.

My code:

```
CREATE TABLE IM20190930
( 
    FACILITY_NUMBER varchar(255), 
    CUSTOMER_NUMBER varchar(255), 
    BRANCH_CODE varchar(255),
    ACCOUNT_STATUS varchar(255), 
    SEGMENT_RULE_ID varchar(255), 
    PD_SEGMENT varchar(255),
    RATING_CODE varchar(255), 
    EXCHANGE_RATE varchar(255), 
    GROUP_SEGMENT varchar(255),
    DOWNLOAD_DATE varchar(255), 
    OUTSTANDING varchar(255), 
    BI_COLLECTABILITY varchar(255),
    DAY_PAST_DUE varchar(255)
)

BULK INSERT dbo.IM20190930 
FROM 'c:\Users\Emily\Desktop\IM20190930.txt'
WITH
    (FIELDTERMINATOR=',',
     ROWTERMINATOR='|',
     KEEPNULLS)
```

Comment: No, not really, the bulk insert is fast just **because** you cannot pick and choose, cannot transform while importing, cannot do other stuff - it's just a very quick *load the data" operation, but it's not flexible

Answer (score 0):

You can use the FORMATFILE = 'format_file_path' option to specify the mapping between file source and table columns.
A format file can be expressed in text or XML.
[From the doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/create-a-format-file-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)